# Integration over the ellipsoid $M:=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1\}$ using the divergence theorem with a vector field

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have troubles with the following question:

Given is the following vector field :
$$f(x,y,z)= \begin{pmatrix}x+\sin(y)\cos(z)\\y+e^{x^2+y^2}\\-z + \log(1+x^2+y^2)\end{pmatrix}$$

and the set $M$ is defined by
$$M:=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1\}$$

Calculate the following integral :
$$\int_M\langle f, v \rangle\, dS$$ 
where $v$ is the unit normal field (german : Einheitsnormalenfeld) toward the exterior.

---

So I thought about using the divergence theorem as usual given that $M$ is just the border of an ellipsoid. I get the triple integral over $1+2ye^{x^2+y^2}$ . The 3 integrals over 1 give us the  volume of a normal ellipsoid, in this case $8\pi$, but how do I integrate $\iiint_{\text{Ellipsoid}} 2ye^{x^2+y^2} dx\,dy\,dz$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are asking how to set up a triple integral?

The ellipsoid $x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4}+ \frac{z^2}{9}= 1$ can be covered by taking $x$ from $-1$ to $1$; $y$, for each $x$, from $-2\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to $2\sqrt{1-x^2}$; and $z$, for each $x$ and $y$, from $-3\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}}$ to $3\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}}$.

So the integral will be $$\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-2\sqrt{1- x^2}}^{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}\int_{z=-3\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}}}^{3\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}}}\left(1+ 2ye^{x^2+y^2}\right)dz\,dy\,dx$$

Since the integrand is independent of $z$, the first integration gives 
$$-6\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-2\sqrt{1- x^2}}^{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}\sqrt{1- x^2}\left(1+ 2ye^{x^2+y^2}\right)dy\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, but isn't that really "complicated" ? I mean, the integral over 1 is easy, and the divergence of the vector field is also a lot easier than in "first" appearence, so do we really need to integrate $2ye^{x^2+y^2}$ in that way ? Isn't there a trick, or couldn't we for example use cylindrical/ spherical coordinates to make things easier ? I found this question in an old exam, and given that time in exam is often limited, the questions are generally not "that" hard, so I'm just a bit surprised.

Comment: The first integral is an integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval, thus the entire calculation yields zero.